# Clicking links in an snap opens in the wrong instance of Firefox

Tags: firefox, snap

Bit of an odd one.

In a reasonably clean install of 20.04, when I click links in a Snap installed application it opens them in a new instance of Firefox. This version has no settings - it is a completely clean Firefox. Gnome thinks this Firefox is part of the parent application, and gives me a new blob on that application and places it within the application group when I super-tab.

It seems that it is only classically confined Snaps that display this behaviour. So Slack opens in one of these magic "clean" Firefox, Telegram in the running instance.

I can't think what else to check. Help!

Comment: is Firefox installed as a snap, or from `apt`, or some other way (or more than one way)?

Comment: It's the default apt version. Not the snap.

Comment: Apparently, firefox launched from a snap sees the "home" of that snap, and thus launches with a fresh profile. For example, the $HOME folder that a snap application like chromium sees is something like: /home/$USER/snap/chromium/1328